# What are these sets?

Tags: convex-analysis, definition

Let $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $T$ be convex and such that if $a \in T$ than $-a \in T$. How is $T$ called? Is it a class of sets which is denominated in some way and studied?

Answer (score 1):

Rudin calls these sets "balanced sets". Convex-analysts call them "centrally symmetric".